# Does a Virtual Machine stop malware from doing harm?

Tags: malware, virtualization

I would like to know if it is safe for the host system of a virtual machine (VM - VirtualBox OSE in my case) to execute malware.

Can a virus break out and read or write data from the host system? Can it establish an Internet connection if I disable it in my VM?

Is a VM a safe environment to try to find out what a virus does?

Can a fork bomb "kill" the host system if I reduce the memory to about 1/4 of my total real memory? How much CPU-time/resources can it use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure are virtual machines really? False sense of security?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3056/971) and [How to ensure that VirtualBox guests can't break out of the vm to get access to the host machine?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4097/971).

Comment: Worth noting that while escaping from the VM is difficuly, detecting that you're in one is simpler (eg checking co-opted interrupts used by the host to communicate with VM client software in the guest). A number pieces of malware now check if they're in a VM and do nothing if they are, to make detection harder.

Comment: @Basic Very interesting! Could you give a reference for one which does so (e.g. a news article / paper)?

Comment: Of course. See [here](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/intelligence/2014/02/a-look-at-malware-with-virtual-machine-detection/) and [here](https://securityintelligence.com/virtual-machines-malware-authors-being-watched/). My work only touches malware tangentially but one of the systems we integrate with works by opening email attachments (and similar) in a VM and monitoring what happens. They've had to go to some quite extreme lengths to get around malware that plays dead when in a test VM (That is, it checks if it's a VM, then checks if it looks like a production one before acting).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Theoretically, the guest system is totally isolated by the VM and cannot even "see" the host, let alone attack it; so the guest cannot break out of the VM. Of course, in practice, [it has occasionally happened](http://www.darkreading.com/security-services/167801101/security/application-security/217701908/hacking-tool-lets-a-vm-break-out-and-attack-its-host.html) ([web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130202223332/http://www.darkreading.com/security-services/167801101/security/application-security/217701908/hacking-tool-lets-a-vm-break-out-and-attack-its-host.html)). An attack requires exploiting a security issue (i.e. a programming bug which turns out to have nasty consequences) in the VM implementation or, possibly, the hardware features on which the VM builds on. There are few exit routes for data out of the VM; e.g., for Internet access, the VM is emulating a virtual network card, which deals only with the lowest level packets, not full TCP/IP -- thus, most IP-stack issues remain confined within the VM itself. So bugs leading to breakout from VM tend to remain rare occurrences.

There are some kinds of attacks against which VM are very effective, e.g. fork bombs. From the point of view of the host system, the VM is a single process. A fork bomb in the guest will bring to its knees the scheduler in the *guest* OS, but for the host this will be totally harmless. Similarly for memory: the VM emulates a physical machine with a given amount of RAM, and will need about that amount of "real" RAM to back it up efficiently. Regardless of what the guest does, the VM will never monopolize more RAM than that. (You still want to limit VM RAM size to, say, at most 1/2 of your physical RAM size, because the extra "real" RAM is handy for disk caching; and the host OS will want to use some, too.)

Comment: At the bottom of this answer there is provided a list with dozen of links to chroot/virtualbox vulnerabilities and suggests there is infinity of these. It doesn't look rare. See: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/330/running-a-virtual-machine-vm-that-can-only-connect-through-tor/376#376

Comment: If you look at the link he posted, that particular attack required a folder on the host machine to be shared with the virtual environment. I do not know about anyone else, but if I am testing malware in a VM, I am not going to be sharing a folder on my host environment with it.

Comment: Perhaps the safe approach would be to use something like a Linux host OS and use Windows in the Virtual box. This way even if you share a folder, the malware or virus won't be able to propagate any further than the folder, because it's a different OS (assuming you have disabled networking in the virtual box OS)

Comment: If some malicious code aims at corrupting hardware i.e. cpu or ram, is it really safe?

Answer (score 32):

> Disclaimer: I'm going for a relatively high-level understanding. If you want a detailed guide, that's out of scope. Additionally, there are other ways (entirely in software) to implement virtual machines to which this does not apply. I am also focusing on "breaking out" through the virtualisation mechanisms only - i.e. not ones that can happen PC-to-PC on actual hard networked hosts.

I like detail, so here we go with some. Firstly, codeproject has some excellent assembler references on the [different modes of an x86 CPU (real, protected and long)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/asm.aspx) and use of [virtualisation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/vmx.aspx). There's an [Intel VT blog](http://virtualizationtechnologyvt.blogspot.com/2009/04/first-look-at-vmxon.html) (I'm not sure if Intel write this) and lastly the first part of the [Rootkit Arsenal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1598220616) is dedicated to explaining x86 and is an excellent read, complete with walkthroughs and nice diagrams. Understanding it all takes patience, so what I'll do here is to give a very brief introduction to how it works.

**The way we rocked when we ran DOS**

DOS and early 16-bit real mode systems operate a segmented memory model. There is no control over the size of segments and there are no protection switches on any of those segments. Code gets loaded into a segment of memory and it runs; it can far jump into other segments, so any code, anywhere can alter anything, including producing a TSR (terminate and stay resident) piece of code that simply points one of the IVT entries (interrupt vector table) at an address in its space, before executing the original. Basically, there is no protection. None. Nada.

**The rise of 32-bit protected mode**

Protected mode gets complicated quickly. There are three parts to it - segmentation, paging and PAE. Each requires a table of data that tells the CPU about that segment, page or helps it extend the address space (PAE). These include the famous ring flags (they apply to segments and pages) which implement process isolation. Paging is your way to load data out of RAM and onto disk and create fancy things like virtual memory (see, the word virtual! We're getting there!)

**Long mode**

Long mode does away with segmentation and simply mandates the PAE/Paging structures. Again, to totally trivialise implementing an OS, Paging is controlled by structures in memory which are then set up via special instructions. Voila, one can achieve process isolation with the right settings. Again, I'm trivialising slightly...

**Give me virtualisation!**

Okay. Virtualisation is the *same general concept*. Virtual machines are set up using virtual machine control structures which dictate how their memory is mapped back to physical memory, *kinda like paging*. Crucially, under certain conditions the virtual machine will be required to ask the host operating system for something, *kinda like process isolation, kinda like a software interrupt*. These are referred to VM exits and provide information to the host such as the state of registers on exit. *Kinda just like a system call*.

**Can a piece of malware break out of a virtual machine?**

So, as far as the VM is concerned, the host OS has all its own memory space and can be infected/damaged/destroyed as it pleases.

In terms of affecting the host memory directly, the virtual machine cannot, because it cannot see it. The host must map the required memory into the virtual machine space. It must also, in that memory space, implement everything from the BIOS up. In order to communicate with certain host devices for certain tasks, the host machine must set up those VM exit conditions and the target VM must trigger them. When that happens, control is transferred to the host.

There are, therefore, two possible at-risk areas:

1. The actions the host takes in response to a VM exit. If there are any bugs in this handling it may be possible to persuade the host to execute something it shouldn't.
2. Any host access to the guest machine's memory space. Remember the host machine code running in ring 0 can waltz in and crash the party wherever it so pleases. It just so happens that you can set the guest's memory from the guest (surprisingly).

This leads you to your exploit mechanism. You need a handling bug in the VM exit routine, then you need to be able to persuade that code to execute some memory, ideally code you just put into a page from the guest vm. Once done, say bye to Kansas.

As Tom Leek says, VMs are incredibly effective in defending against fork bombs. In a similar vein to the way the OS can limit how much memory a process can allocate, so it can limit how much memory is mapped to the VM. Run out and the guest OS believes it is out of physical memory; the host will not allocate it more *unless* you implement a VM exit to do this, which would be a bit dangerous and I do not believe this is done.

**How likely is this?**

Not very. It depends on those VM exit implementations entirely, or reading memory from the guest on the host with a nice bug in your reading code. It also requires that said bug would allow you to control the crash in such a way that you can force execution to the memory address your host holds. The VM exit must be able to access that memory.

**What I have not covered?**

1. Attacks on existing software stacks such as TCPIP. The vulnerabilities here are the same as if you had two actual phsyical PCs anyway.
2. Entirely software implemented virtualisation.
3. Virtualisation on any other type of chip. This applies to Intel VT compatible setups.

Finally, [I have previously](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/why-arent-applications-sandboxed-in-windows/8682#8682) argued that process isolation is a form of sandboxing. Reading that answer and this one, you should now be able to understand why I define them that way. There are remarkable similarities between process isolation and virtual machines in x86.

**Update**

So, I've dug around even more on this, especially into the blue pill research. What I've described is a very simplistic high level view. I've found more detail. Here's a [whole paper dedicated to it](http://www.invisiblethingslab.com/resources/2011/Software%20Attacks%20on%20Intel%20VT-d.pdf) from Invisible Things Lab. It turns out that their [defences](http://invisiblethingslab.com/resources/bh08/part2-full.pdf) talk included the concept of denying execute access to user mode pages from ring 0, thereby preventing direct execution of data the virtual machine has placed into memory. [It turns out this is being implemented in Intel CPUs](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2011/06/from-slides-to-silicon-in-3-years.html) and patches currently exist in the Linux Kernel. So, depending on how that goes, it may well be the case that attacks of this nature become much harder, even if exploits exist.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but there's also virtual 8086 mode, unreal mode, and probe mode on many processors too.

Comment: physical typo What I have not covered? 1. Can't make change needs to involve 6 characters. What a stupid rule!

Answer (score 13):

I have done quite a bit of malware experimentation within a VM - mostly using backtrack4 to break in from one host to the next. I'm a VMware Workstation user, primarily.

The largest issue comes from the possibility of the network connection of your VM transferring back to your host OS. You want to totally disable networking and / or use a network which has no access back to your host.

Limiting memory is a good best practice. I generally keep it to about a quarter, same as you. The CPU time is limited to either the number of cores or (if you have finer grained controls in your software) the percentage of CPU time defined for your specific VM.

Targeted attacks capable of breaking out of the virtual environment do exist and are commercially available - such as the cloudburst @Hendrick mentions - but are relatively rare. Keeping up to date on your virtualization patches is a very good idea.

See [here](http://www.darkreading.com/security-services/167801101/security/application-security), [here](http://searchcloudsecurity.techtarget.com/news/2240033598/Terremark-on-cloud-computing-risks-legal-subpoenas/217701908/index.html), and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security) for details.

Comment: The other piece to be aware of is the use of VMWare tools, which are a standard method of communicating back to the host, through the virtualized hardware.  This is just another path, and one I don't know of any vulns for off the top of my head.

Comment: Good point. I generally don't install VMware tools unless I have a defined need.

Comment: @MToecker, one path with VMWare tools is shared drives. If you have write access to files on the host machine from within the guest, so does any piece of malware.

Comment: What do you mean by "There has been no precedence to date for breaking through the virtualization layer"? Google finds [Exploit in the shared folder implementation](http://www.coresecurity.com/content/advisory-vmware) and [Exploit in the graphic card simulation](http://goo.gl/xM8aI) as the first two hits. I am sure that spending more than 2 minutes on a search will result in a lot more vulnerabilities.

Comment: The only things that I've seen have been in regards to the VMware tools. Thanks for bringing up the cloudburst stuff. I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to all the good information here about whether the virus can escape out of the VM, let me point out another issue to consider:

It is possible for malicious code to [detect whether it is being executed inside a virtual machine or not](http://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/Virtual_Machine_Threats.pdf).  This often goes by the name [virtual machine detection](http://www.s21sec.com/descargas/vmware-eng.pdf) or ["red pills"](http://www.usenix.org/event/woot09/tech/full_papers/paleari.pdf), and there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154163/781723) [techniques](http://my.opera.com/jaelanicu/blog/just-another-vm-detection-was-vm-detection-combo) available.

Moreover, some viruses and other malware use these techniques to detect whether they are being run in a VM, and if so, shut off their payload (avoid taking any malicious action).  They do this to try to make life harder for folks to reverse-engineer the malware or detect it.

Consequently, a VM is not a good way to find out what a piece of malware does.  The malware may not be able to break out of the VM, but at the same time, it might not do anything when it is running inside the VM.  If you run it in the VM and see it does nothing, decide it is harmless, and then decide to run it outside the VM -- you could get owned.  Be careful out there.

Answer (score -2):

What ever you guys means, Enabling the Bios Setting to interact with your Computer, these shall be easy to manipulate or crack by the hacker. I guess if the software that you use online would be  hacked. simple as that it would be much better to buy Memory extension than to allow Online software application to deal with it. this thoughts are just certain point of view. well, believe it or not having study online  for hackers nowadays, there are abundant that you cant imagine they said its over millions over the world.

Comment: What are you trying to say? I don't undstand. Please rephrase your answer.