# Can a hacker who has entered a virtual honeypot attack a LAN?

Tags: honeypot

Is it possible for a hacker who has entered a honeypot (running in a virtual machine e.g. virtualbox), to attack real computers on a LAN?

Comment: You don't use a honeypot to attack. Yes you can configure a virtual machine to be in the same subnet of the other machines in the LAN.

Comment: You can certainly use a virtual machine to launch attacks on a LAN, but it would not be a honeypot.  A honeypot, by definition, is a machine designed to BE attacked, not a machine designed to attack.

Comment: Sorry did not write the question properly. Have edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Does a Virtual Machine stop malware from doing harm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9011/does-a-virtual-machine-stop-malware-from-doing-harm) & [Breaking out of the virtualization layer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30161/breaking-out-of-the-virtualization-layer) as a reference.

It *could* be possible. It would require a misconfigured VM network, shared access between the host and the VM or some other type of exploit to break out of the VM.