# How do you visit a link without risking your computer?

Tags: web-browser, malware

I got a link to `http://61.19.247.192/~naowit/dustin.html`, which was masked as a youtube.com link via email. Now I'm not willing to visit it because I know it's probably got some type of malware on it, or at the very least a scam/phishing attempt.

But... I'm always curious when I get these links. I want to visit them to see what they are up to. I have Sandboxie, but is that secure enough if I simply run the browser in a sandbox?

In general, how should you visit links that you are unsure of? I always have NoScript running, but I know that's not enough.

Comment: You could download the target page with wget, a self written program, telnet ;-), or something else and view/analyze it in plain text.

Comment: The site redirects you to another domain with an online drugstore. Remember, don't but these things on the internet but from your local store after consultation of your doctor.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Hi Greg, welcome to [security.se]. Please take a moment to read the [FAQ]. Btw, I'm pretty sure there was another very similar question here, that already has some very good answers, but I cant find it now.

Comment: @David - I'm using Windows7 64bit

Comment: @Ordag - I've used wget on my Linux server, wasn't sure there was a Windows version of it? I did a quick google and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm is the first result, but the website is down for me.

Comment: @AviD - Hi, thanks for the welcome. This site is pretty amazing so far.

Comment: @Greg On Windows I'd using the present PowerShell: `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://whatever") > whatever.txt`

Answer (score 6):

If you're of a technical nature, you may like [Malzilla](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/). Old school folks may appreciate [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)

Both are text only ways of accessing a web page.  Malzilla provides diagnostics useful per-page, and Lynx is a text based browser.

But I only use them when I'm suspicious of something.  In the meantime I just use Chrome or IE in a virtual machine. I like [Oracle's Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) since it allows me to use a 64 bit client OS, where other virtualization solutions don't

Comment: Hi Makerofthigns7, I've haven't heard of either of those; I'll read up on both. I have a couple VM applications installed already actually (for class); so I'll just install another Windows 7 for purposes like this only. However, while searching for answers, I found this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12546/is-it-safe-to-install-malware-in-a-vm  - so VM's are safe, but not 100 percent apparently. Maybe I'll double up and use Sandboxie inside a VM.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Lynx, and use it fairly often. Sometimes it's fun to see what sort of muck people are trying to get up to.

Comment: I like Malzilla, it hasn't been updated in about 5 years though sadly :(

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous technologies you can use.  It all depends on your OS and how far you want to go.

On Windows, the easiest is to use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) to sandbox your browser.  On Linux/BSD you could setup a chroot or jail to run the browser from.

Another choice is to set up a virtual machine using Vmware, KVM , Xen, VirtualBox or Parallels and run a  browser in there.  This will require you to install a full OS, but will give you an extra level of isolation.

The easiest thing to do, is to delete the email and forget about the link.  No point in playing with fire.

Comment: Ok, I'll give Sandboxie a try. I've had it for years, but I've never really used it for security reasons. I always used it to run 2 instances of the same program. lol

Answer (score 0):

I have always spun up a quick VM and opened in there. I know this sounds like a lot of work just to check a link, but if you have VMs already running...no big deal.