# Virtual Box security

Tags: virtualization, hardening

I am using virtual box to run a secure machine. I am not fully confident in the hosts security. My assumptions are that of course the host can read the VM when the VM is running and that if the machine is not running and some one got into my computer ripping the VB image would not be useful if it was encrypted.

Is there a way to make the VM more secure while it is running?

Are there settings on the virtual machine that will make it more secure against the host machine?

Can I assume that the VM is secured so long as it is not running and using an encrypted home drive? ( Default Encrypted home Ubuntu 12.04 LTS settings )

Comment: The more you make the VM <i>unshared</i> with the Host Machine, more security you'll have! <br>
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the manual of virtual box? It provides a lot of guidance for securing VM.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch13.html

In addition, your questions are little bit vague. Could you explain more details on what you want to achieve?