# Why an infected VM does not affect the host machine?

Tags: virus, windows-xp

I installed a Windows XP virtual machine on VirtualBox. The host machine is also a Windows XP. I run 5 viruses on the guest machine, however this does not seem to infect my host machine. Could someone inform me why ?

Comment: Thats not true always, please read the previous answers on this topic [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security)

Comment: I am using a Host network only option , but no shared folders between the guest and the host: could this infect my host machine anyway ?