# VirtualBox file sharing: is there a security difference between never having done it and having done it but now disabled it?

Tags: virtualization

I'm thinking of getting started with VirtualBox but for security reasons I would like to keep file sharing off. However, there are certainly some files I'd like to transfer from host to guest. Would enabling file sharing and disabling it after I've completed the transfer open my system to vulnerabilities it would not have had if I had never enabled file sharing in the first place? If so, are there better (safer) ways of transferring files?

Comment: I will suggest you to check out this existing thread. Let me know if it answers you. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security

Comment: @Vaibs I understand that virtualization (even with file sharing turned off) doesn't completely remove risk, but I'm more focused on whether I would be at *greater* risk for having once enabled file sharing then turning it off as compared to having never enabled it at all.